# how to rename groups of nested columns in pandas?

Tags: pandas

The dataframe in pandas looks like that:

[image]

I need to rename them correspondingly to
`buy_1`, `buy_2`, `buy_3`, ... `sell_1`,  `sell_2`

What is the most efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `format`

```
df.columns = df.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df.set_axis(df.columns.map('_'.join),axis=1)
```

If your second level is `int` and not `str`, either of the below would work with still using `join()`.

```
df.set_axis(df.rename(str,axis=1).columns.map('_'.join),axis=1)

df.set_axis(df.columns.map(lambda x: '_'.join([str(i) for i in x])),axis=1)

df.set_axis(df.columns.set_levels(df.columns.levels[1].astype(str),level=1).map('_'.join),axis=1)
```

Comment: will not work is the level 2 are int ~

Comment: yeah good point